# ¿como se pone el texto del div izquierdo alineado a la izquierda y abajo?

Tags: html, css

[image: asi es como esta][image: asi es cmo lo necesito]necesito el texto del div "izda" que son 2 líneas, quede en la parte baja para que quede alineado por abajo con el texto del lado derecho (div "dcho") que son 7 líneas.
gracias anticipadamente!

```css
.cabecera {
    background-color: #2c2b2b;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2% 5% 1% 5%;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    overflow: auto;

}   


.izda {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    min-width: 500px;
}


.dcha {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.dcha p{
    font-family: "Lobster";
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: deepskyblue;
}

h1{
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
    <div class="izda">
      <h1>Promociones Comerciales</h1>
    <h5>Las mejores promociones para tu negocio!</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="dcha">
      <p>Seguros<br>Hipotecas<br>Imprenta<br>Copistería<br>Rotulación<br>Merchandising<br>...</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando Flexbox, declaramos al contenedor que tenga `display: flex` y a tu div `.izda` le declaramos `align-self: flex-end;`

```css
.cabecera {
  background-color: #2c2b2b;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2% 5% 1% 5%;
  font-family: 'Questrial';
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.izda {
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 500px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.dcha {
  width: 30%;
}

.dcha p {
  font-family: "Lobster";
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="izda">
    <h1>Promociones Comerciales</h1>
    <h5>Las mejores promociones para tu negocio!</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="dcha">
    <p>
      Seguros
      <br> Hipotecas
      <br> Imprenta
      <br> Copistería
      <br> Rotulación
      <br> Merchandising
      <br> ...
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias! ha salido bien pero no es responsive, el bloque de texto derecho, si la ventana es pequeña no se pone debajo del otro, como lo arreglo?

Comment: @Basicmix puedes hacerlo con `flex-wrap: wrap`, edité mi respuesta con lo que me pediste

Comment: genial, va perfecto!! muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien lo que quieres lograr, pero te dejo este código, espero que te ayude.

```css
.cabecera {
    background-color: #2c2b2b;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2% 5% 1% 5%;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    overflow: auto;

}   


.izda {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.dcha {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dcha p{
    font-family: "Lobster";
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: deepskyblue;
}

h1{
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">

    <div class="izda">
      <h1>Promociones Comerciales</h1>
      <h5>Las mejores promociones para tu negocio!</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dcha">
      <p>Seguros<br>Hipotecas<br>Imprenta<br>Copistería<br>Rotulación<br>Merchandising<br>...</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: no funciona, lo que quiero es que el texto de la izquierda vaya abajo del todo

Comment: Podrías enviar una gráfica para ver que es lo que quieres exactamente?

Comment: he subido 2 imagenes, la 1a. es como esta, y la 2a. es como lo necesito, con el texto del div izdo. abajo. gracias!!